# solve diophantine equation $2x^2(x^2-1)=3(y^2-1)$ and verify apparent equivalence

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Here is a screenshot excerpt of a paper titled "The Strong Law of Small Numbers" by Richard Guy on number theory

[image]

I tried to tackle the seemingly simpler equation

$$2x^2(x^2-1)=3(y^2-1)$$

I got to

$$6y^2-(2x^2-1)^2=5$$

which looks like Pell equations but it must be different since it has only the solutions mentioned in the paper.

In addition I conjecture that the two equations of the paper are equivalent but don't how to prove it still .

thanks for any help.

Comment: the paper
https://www.ime.usp.br/~rbrito/docs/2322249.pdf